# Values in subprocesses deviating from main thread

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-2.x, pool

I wrote this simple program.

```
import multiprocessing


d = {"what":'1'}
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def square(x):
    print("Adding process:", x)
    d[x]=x
    print("Inner d", d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(square, range(0, 5))
    pool.close()
    print(d)
```

Output

```
('Adding process:', 0)
('Inner d', {0: 0, 'what': '1'})
('Adding process:', 1)
('Inner d', {0: 0, 1: 1, 'what': '1'})
('Adding process:', 2)
('Inner d', {0: 0, 1: 1, 'what': '1', 2: 2})
('Adding process:', 3)
('Inner d', {0: 0, 1: 1, 'what': '1', 3: 3, 2: 2})
('Adding process:', 4)
('Inner d', {0: 0, 1: 1, 'what': '1', 3: 3, 4: 4, 2: 2})
{'what': '1'}
```

I am new to multiprocessing, so I wanted to know. How do I reload the value of `d` in the sub processes.

Comment: Each subprocess runs in it's own memory-space, so there are no globally shared variables.

Comment: Is there a way I can share memory/update memory in the processes @martineau

Comment: Yes, in Python 3.8 they added a [`multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) class.

Comment: @martineau We are using python2 at work so can't really use that, anyother suggestion?

Comment: You might be able to do it with the [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#module-mmap) module on Unix and Windows.

Comment: Multiprocessing **is not** multithreading. This is important to understand. Here is the links to the [relevant section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) regarding sharing state between processes. Generally, it is best avoided if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to share a dictionary across multiple processes is to use a *managed* dictionary created by an instance of a `SyncManager`, which is returned when you call `multiprocessing.Manager()`. This is a fairly complicated topic. When you create such a dictionary, what is returned is a reference to a `proxy` for the dictionary being managed by the `Syncmanager` and consequently when you execute methods on the dictionary you are in essence executing something more akin to a remote procedure call, which can be somewhat slower than if you were operating on a standard, local dictionary.

In the code below, a pool initializer is used to initialize global variable `d` for each process in the pool with the reference to the dictionary proxy:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
import time


def init_pool(the_dict):
    global d
    # initialize the global for each process in the pool:
    d = the_dict

def square(x):
    print("Adding process:", x, flush=True)
    d[x]=x
    print("Inner d", d, flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        d['what'] = '1'
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(d,))
        pool.map(square, range(0, 5))
        pool.close() # not necessary
        print(d)
```

Prints:

```
Adding process: 0
Inner d {'what': '1', 0: 0}
Adding process: 1
Inner d {'what': '1', 0: 0, 1: 1}
Adding process: 2
Inner d {'what': '1', 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
Adding process: 3
Inner d {'what': '1', 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
Adding process: 4
Inner d {'what': '1', 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
{'what': '1', 0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}
```

**Update**

For Python 2, which doesn't support `flush=True` on the `print` statement, printing in parallel presents more of a problem trying to prevent interleaving of the printing across processes. Here we use a lock to ensure that printing is done serially:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager, Lock
import time
import sys


def init_pool(the_dict, the_lock):
    global d
    global lock
    # initialize the global for each process in the pool:
    d = the_dict
    lock = the_lock

def square(x):
    d[x]=x
    with lock:
        print "Adding process:", x, "\nInner d", d
        sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        d['what'] = '1'
        lock = Lock()
        pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(d, lock))
        pool.map(square, range(0, 5))
        pool.close() # not necessary
        print d
```